# Cron job not working on Bitnami AWS Lightsale

Tags: wordpress, cron, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

We are using gptaipower plugin in WordPress, for Schedule tasks we need to add the below cron job as per their documentation: https://gptaipower.com/how-to-add-cron-job/.

```
* * * * * php /opt/bitnami/wordpress/index.php -- wpaicg_cron=yes
```

We are using AWS Lightsale LAMP_PHP_7 the cron never worked.

The plugin support said, it might work by adding the below cron job in the crontab -e

```
* * * * * /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php  /opt/bitnami/wordpress/index.php -- wpaicg_cron=yes
```

The result is: the cron never run.
We checked Bitnami documentation: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/moodle/configuration/install-cron/

we are not sure how to make this cron to work.

Comment: i am having crontab issues also on Lightsail for a Laravel application running PHP 8.1

Comment: did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

After I run

which php I got `/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php`

and my cron code is:

`* * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs && /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

run `sudo service cron reload` to reload the crons